# Joomla 3.2 installation file/directory ownership issues

Tags: php, permissions, ftp, joomla3.0, file-ownership

I am trying to install Joomla 3.2 using the host provided by my university. So, I have available one mysql database with the username and pass and the ftp username and pass to transfer data, only. That is, no Cpanel installed or ssh available.

If I extract the file Joomla_3.2.0-Stable-Full_Package.zip and ftp the contents on the website, the owner of these files/folders is user "ftp_username". I can continue to install Joomla only if I set-up the ftp layer.

This works, except I get from time to time messages like --> JFTP: :rename: Bad response Rename failed More specifically I get this message when using kunena.

Moreover, I read online that the FTP layer shouldn't be used normally. Also, the tmp/cache/logs create permission problems.

If I remove the ftp layer (by editing the configuration.php) then I cannot modify anything since Joomla cannot modify the files (owned by ftp_username). Of course, I could change all permissions to 777, but that would be suicide...

I found a post explaining a bit the situation I'm [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Why_can%27t_you_install_any_extensions%3F)! Especially the advice on using "chmod 4770" is feasible but I don't know about how secure it is (haven't tried it).

Anyone has an idea how I can make this work?

cross-posted [here](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=707&t=827776)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to bypass this problem. Not worth it if you have an alternative provider!

1. I installed joomla with ftp layer
2. I installed Extplorer plugin
3. Used plugin to upload Joomla_3.2.0-Stable-Full_Package.zip on the server. Now the file is owned by the apache user.
4. Deleted all the (joomla installation) files on the server except the zip file
5. Uploaded a php script to unzip the file using php (http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php). The installation folders/files are now owned by apache user
6. Reinstall Joomla without the ftp layer.

I guess I could have used some php uploader script instead of steps 1-4, but I already had Joomla installed with the ftp layer.

That's it. Up and working. If you have an alternative provider, don't bother.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the hosting option provided by the university may be too restrictive to work for pretty much any CMS.  You need to be able to chmod and potentially chown all your files in bulk so as to avoid insanity.

There may be an FTP program out there that will chmod your files as you are uploading them.  If your group is www-data or whatever group apache needs, then you can 775 your folders and 664 your files; you should be good to go.

Comment: Filezilla takes care of chmod, but chown not. I tried to chown the files to www-data through a php script, but I guess I don't have the rights... Thanks anyway, I'll try contacting the university IT department.

Comment: I used to work at a university.  A box of donuts goes a long way.